# What does this condition do?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

```
<c:if test="${not empty userList)}">
    <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr class="even">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>About You</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user" varStatus="status">
            <tr class="<c:if test="${status.count % 2 == 0}">even</c:if>">
                <td>${user.name}</td>
                <td>${user.gender}</td>
                <td>${user.country}</td>
                <td>${user.aboutYou}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

When i remove  `<c:if test="${not empty userList)}"></c:if>` it throws me error.
What does this condition check? My DB tables has users list, but yet this entire code is not displayed in my HTML itself.

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: and I guess we are mediums and we see through your machine what the error is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that line is equivalent to

```
if(userList!=null && userList.size()>0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the list contains data if so the foreach can be used. If you use a foreach on an empty or null list it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> *When i remove `<c:if test="${not empty userList)}"></c:if>` it throws me error.*

That surprises me. I would expect it to be the *other way round*. I would expect that the error disappears when you remove that line. It's namely syntactically invalid. The following is syntactically valid:

```
<c:if test="${not empty userList}">
```

In future questions, please post the exact error message and trace as well. They namely tell something about the cause of the problem. You know, once the cause of a certain problem is *understood*, then the solution would speak for itself.